# How to install the Grunt task runner?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to install Grunt (on Windows).

The documentation (http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) says to install grunt-cli and explains that this is not the Grunt task runner but just the program to allow the grunt command to be run from any folder. Ok. Fine. I've done that. My next question is; how to install the Grunt task runner. The implication of the docs is that this will be installed locally in my project directory.

How do I do that?

The project already has a Gruntfile.js and a package.json & works on another machine. I'm just trying to get it run locally.

Specifically I get this message:

"... a Gruntfile wasn't found or Grunt hasn't been installed locally to your project"

Thanks

--Justin Wyllie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install --save-dev grunt` to install it just like any module and add it to your `package.json` file as a development dependency.

`grunt` may also already be listed as a dependency, in which case you may just need to run `npm install` to install all dependencies.

Comment: It could also be useful to note that since the project works on another machine, Grunt is probably already listed as a dev dependency in his package.json. If that's the case, Grunt and all the project's other npm dependencies can be installed locally with just `npm install`

Comment: Ok. It was and just doing npm install worked. Thanks. .... In the package.json there is field 'main' with the value 'grunt.js'. However grunt is using Gruntfile.js. (grunt.js is hanging around from a previous project and I can get rid of it). But what is that 'main' field about?

Comment: Also, sorry, does the directory node-modules need to be there? Can this go in the main system location where grunt-cli is?

Comment: Generally each node project has its own `node_modules` folder for it's specific dependency versions. `main` defines the file that is loaded when you `require(...)` a module, so in this case requiring the module would return the `exports` object from `grunt.js`.